# Components of the fully contravariant Kronecker Delta in Schwarzschild Metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, covariance

I thought the kronecker delta $\delta^{\mu\nu}$ should always be of value $1$ if both indices are equal and $0$ if they are different. However it seems that the delta has components different from $1$ in Schwarzschild Basis. Could someone elaborate how to calculate such components and explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index structure of the Kronecker delta is $\delta^\mu_\nu$, not $\delta_{\mu\nu}$ OR $\delta^{\mu\nu}$. In ANY coordinate system, $\delta^\mu_\nu$ has value 1 if both indices are equal and 0 if they are different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am asking this question here because I do not have complete knowledge regarding differential geometry. Nontheless I was asked to calculate the components of the fully contravariant form of the Kronecker delta in the Schwarzschild Metric. It came from an exam question without answer and carries 4 marks, so I thought the answer would probably not be 1,0 as the delta in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: The fully covariant form of the Kronecker delta is just the metric since $g_{\mu\rho} \delta^\rho_\nu = g_{\mu\nu}$ and the fully contravariant form is the inverse metric $g^{\mu\rho} \delta^\nu_\rho = g^{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: The question was clearly asked in a tricky way. What it was really asking you is to write down the inverse metric of the Schwarzschild solution.